# Automatically sync two computers on OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook

Is there a way to have two computers running OS X (Snow Leopard) automatically sync everything?  I currently have a Macbook Pro and am thinking about getting an iMac also; however, I don't want to have to be transferring things all of the time since I'll be working on the laptop when I'm traveling or out and I would be using the iMac when at my desk at home.  Ideally a mirror image of the laptop on the iMac would be preferred, but I don't know if something like this is possible.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/60398/two-identical-macs/60411#60411

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go and get the obvious iLife reference out of the way. But if you want to go the el-cheapo route you can get creative with a free Dropbox account, including a tutorial I caught in Wired a few months back.

[Sync iCal with dropbox](http://www.aysweb.com/?p=1164)

EDIT: I don't know if your primary concern is with data loss or simply programs/preferences/etc from a system failure, but I'll iterate again that dropbox is a perfect solution for file backup because it is all sync'd automatically.

Comment: Backup isn't actually a concern at all because I already have a Time Capsule that backs up.  Basically I just don't want to have to be transferring files from one computer to the other all of the time.  I have thought about Dropbox (which may be what I have to end up using), but I didn't know if there was something that would sync all files instead of just what I put in there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DirSyncPro](http://directorysync.sourceforge.net/index.html).  I don't think it's automatic, however I believe you can set it up for a manual kick off.  I haven't tried it yet but I plan to soon.  Also it's in java so will work with Windows, Linux as well as OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to happen online? Or is it OK when everything is synced when at home. In the last case, you could download Synkron and set it up to sync all the folders you like at any time you like over the local network.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).  It is a fast and efficient program and can work securely over ssh.  It takes a little setting up but you can run it on the command line (and automatically do it periodically using [cron](http://benr75.com/pages/using_crontab_mac_os_x_unix_linux)).

Answer (score 0):

rsync comes with the machine and will allow you to selectively sync folders E.g. Home folder etc