# Syncing two local folders "dropbox/owncloud" style in linux

Tags: linux, sync

I would like to sync two local folders in a way that dropbox or owncloud do it - with a notion of history, so that it is possible to distinguish if a file got deleted in folder A o added in foler B.
(If you are wondering: one local folder is a cifs mount, that other local computers also use, but this one computer does also travel). The machine in questions runs xubuntu (might switch to fedora).

Also, these folders contain about 100GB of photos - so version control system based solutions probably do not perform so well.

Now rsync does certainly not do the job, as it maintains no history. [This questions](https://superuser.com/questions/31512/how-to-synchronize-the-home-folder-between-multiple-computers) has a few interesting answers, though none seem really suitable to my scenario. The most interesting suggestion seems to be unison, but it seems to be not really maintained any more.

I could probably set up an owncloud server, but that seems like a lot of overhead for just syncing two folders. Also, the server would need to be installed locally as not to add the dependence on another server running to enable the sync.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

**EDIT** As the cifs share actually resides on a Synology NAS, I might just use Cloud Station. I will try and report back.

Comment: What about things like subversion [SVN](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) or any other version control usually used for code developing?

Comment: It seems that version control based systems are not so good for large photo collection (like http://sparkleshare.org/) - I should have mentioned that. I will update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the edit of my question, I was able to solve this problem using the "Cloud Station" software provided by Synology for the NAS boxes. It initially created a lot of cpu usage on the NAS (understandable, it was probably indexing the large photo share), but over night it synced the whole folder, seems to work fine.

So in the end I set up kind of an owncloud server, but residing on the NAS, so the overhead is rather small.